# Positioning of images

Tags: graphics, positioning

Can somebody help me? I am making some tutorials and I need to add some pictures to document

I want to be able to add three pictures side by side on one line and on the next line can be only one or two pictures, but I have problem: when I have two pictures it is both centered to “two columns” and I need “three columns” where the third one is blank.

Can somebody help me?
Thank you,
Georgerr

My code is:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
      \centering
      {\includegraphics[width=5cm]
      {../images/Mail_Phone/WindowsPhoneMail/EN/08_NastaveniSync.png}}
      \caption{Caption A}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
     {\includegraphics[width=5cm]
     {../images/Mail_Phone/WindowsPhoneMail/EN/09_NastaveniSync2.png}}
     \caption{Caption B}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
\end{figure}
```

[image: What I want]

[image: What I have]

Comment: My guess is, adding `%` to the end of each line may fix things, but without a full compiling code to evaluate, it is tough to say.  Welcome to the site.  Also, try putting something in the last `minipage`, such as `\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}~\end{minipage}%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using a `tabular`, or as here `tabularx` to fill the page width, instead of individual `minipage`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}\\[-1.5em]
    \caption{This is an example image}
    &\caption{This is also an exampe image}
    &\caption{And one more}\\
    %% 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    & \\[-1.5em]
    \caption{More picture}
    &\caption{Next empty}
    &\\
    %%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    & 
    & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}\\[-1.5em]
    \caption{This row has empty in the middle}
    &
    &\caption{This is the last one!}\\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same can be done by use of `minipage`. The problem with the empty slot is that an empty `minipage` colapses to nothing, so you need to put something in it. I use `\strut` but you can also use `~` as suggested in the comments for the question.

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{This is an example image}
  \end{minipage}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{This is also an exampe image}
  \end{minipage}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{One more}
  \end{minipage}%
  \newline
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{More picture}
  \end{minipage}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Next empty}
  \end{minipage}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \strut
  \end{minipage}%
  \newline
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{This row has empty in the middle}
  \end{minipage}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \strut
  \end{minipage}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{This is the last one!}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```